# Android Studio: How can I copy all of the problems to my clipboard?

Tags: android, android-studio, copy, clipboard

I like how android studio shares all the problems for a given file. I can see them in the problems view. However there does not seem to be  a way (that I can find) to copy all to clipboard. It seems I need to copy each one of them. Is there a way to copy all to clipboard so I don't have to manually copy and paste each one?